# passport.authenticate() loads forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to implement Login functionality on my website with passport. If I use passport.authenticate() to log in, when I actually try logging from my website it remains stuck loading forever (although without crashing the website).

```
router.get('/login', (req,res)=>{
     res.render('users/login');
})

router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:"/campgrounds", successFlash:'Welcome', failureRedirect:'/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid Credentials' }));
```

Comment: did you manage to fix this one?